# つけておいてください　translation

Tags: translation, subsidiary-verbs

An example is the following:

> - 電気がついています。けしましょうか。
> - いいえ、つけておいてください。

The question is, can I translate the last part as "Please, leave them turned on", so that the whole translation is:

> - The lights are on. Should I turn them off?
> - No, please, leave them turned on.

How would you translate the phrase "Please leave them turned on"?

Thank you in advance!

Comment: Where did you see this example?

Comment: I don't think you need a comma in the English sentence. "Please, leave them turned on" with a comma sounds to me like "Oh give me a break, leave them turned on".

Comment: @istrasci Just some exercise from Japanese class on how to use ..ておきます　pattern.

Comment: @macraf I guess you're right about comma. 
Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

(Since I cannot comment, I place my translation here)

I will translate like this

> No, please keep it on.

Because the implication is a habit in Japanese. I prefer **"keep it on"** for shorter presentation.

OR

> No, please keep the light on.